# do I need to release the NSCalendar object in this code example?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, nscalendar

do I need to release the NSCalendar object in this code example?  Or will this impact on the fact that the last line of code is to return newDate which is derived from the "gregorian" variable?

```
#import "NSDateHelper.h"


@implementation NSDate(NSDateHelper)

-(NSDate *) setHour:(NSInteger)hour andMinute:(NSInteger)minute {

    // Get Calendar for Existing Date
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components: NSUIntegerMax fromDate: self];

    // Set Hour and Minute
    [components setHour: hour];
    [components setMinute: minute];
    [components setSecond: 00];

    // Create resultant Date
    NSDate *newDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents: components];

    // Clean Up
    [gregorian release];    // TODO:  Do I release this here, or will it affect the return value not being valid?

    return newDate;
}

@end
```

Comment: you should not use `NSUIntegerMax` as dateFlags. It will take much longer to calculate all the unnecessary stuff than just year month and day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Releasing there is fine, `newDate` is returned with an `autorelease` so it will stick around until an `NSAutoreleasePool` is drained. If `newDate` requires a reference to the calendar instance it will handle the retain count internally.

Comment: thanks - thought I should mark this as the answer just as it gives that little bit of extra in terms of the last sentence

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you release.

your components variable will retain what it needs. Since you take ownership by alloc'ing NSCalendar, you are responsible for releasing it.

ps: it is very strange to have a return value for a method named set.  I would recommend refactoring to avoid a lot of confusion later on.

Comment: +1 for the ps. Calling set on a immutable object feels very wrong. I would suggest a name like `dateBySettingHour:andMinute:`

Comment: thanks for the advice on the naming too - new to Objective C here :)

Answer (score 1):

The object that alloc'd it should release it too, unless autorelease is used.

Autorelease is not used in this example, so you must indeed release it.